# getting values from JsonResult

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

trying to build a mvc project, which loads uploaded images from database into a carousel. the problem that i have is, the images will create a byte[] list and send to view from controller as a JsonResult. the problem is i don`t know how to get access to each element that returns from the controller in my JS code in the view.
here is my controller :

```
public JsonResult GetImages(string date, string sessionNumber)
    { 
        int selectedSessionNumber =  Convert.ToInt32(sessionNumber);
        Guid getClassInfoId = (Guid)Session["infoId"];
        var getSessionId= (from c in db.Session
            where c.ClassInfoID ==  getClassInfoId && c.SessionNumber == selectedSessionNumber
            select c.ID).ToList();
        List<byte[]> getPics =new List<byte[]>();

        foreach (var item in getSessionId)
        {           
            getPics.Add((from c in db.ClassPicture where c.SessionID == item select c.PicFile).First());

        }
        List<string> imagesBase64 = new List<string>();
        foreach (var pics in getPics)
        {
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pics);  
            imagesBase64.Add(base64);
        }

        return Json(imagesBase64, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and this is my js code :

```
function ShowImage() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetImages", "Main")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    traditional: true,
                    data: { 'date': selectedDate, 'sessionNumber': selectedSession },
                    success: function (myData) {
                            var imgSrc = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + myData;
                                $('<div class="item"><img src=' +
                                    imgSrc +
                                    '><div class="carousel-caption"></div></div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
                                $('<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to= 0></li>')
                                    .appendTo('.carousel-indicators');
                                //    }
                                //}
                                $('.item').first().addClass('active');
                                $('.carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');
                                $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel(3);


                                //      $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel();
                          }  
                    });
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Specify your jQuery ajax `dataType` to 'JSON' (the data type you're expecting back from the server).
2. Loop over `myData` using `$.each(myData, function(idx, imageBase64) { ... })`.